# Nx Monorepo NestJS TypeORM SQLite: Unable to Connect to the Database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, nestjs, typeorm, monorepo

I am creating a web application using an Nx monorepo which is going to have a NestJS backend and an Angular frontend. I want to use SQLite as database. The SQLite database file name is `my_db.db` which is located in the root of the repo/project. My monorepo general structure is like the following:

```
my-project
│   angular.json
│   decorate-angular-cli.js
│   my_db.db
│   nest-cli.json
│   nx.json
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.base.json
│   yarn.lock
│
├───apps
│   └───api
│       │   .eslintrc.json
│       │   jest.config.js
│       │   tsconfig.app.json
│       │   tsconfig.json
│       │   tsconfig.spec.json
│       │
│       └───src
│           │   main.ts
│           │
│           ├───app
│           │       .gitkeep
│           │       app.module.ts
│           │
│           ├───assets
│           │       .gitkeep
│           │
│           └───environments
│                   environment.prod.ts
│                   environment.ts
│
├───dist
│   └───apps
│       └───api
│           │   main.js
│           │   main.js.map
│           │
│           └───assets
│                   .gitkeep
│
└───libs
    └───back-end-dashboard
        │   tsconfig.lib.json
        │
        └───src
            │   index.ts
            │
            └───lib
                │   back-end-dashboard.module.ts
                │
                ├───controllers
                │       dashboard.controller.ts
                │
                ├───entities
                │       summary.entity.ts
                │
                └───services
                        dashboard.service.ts
```

Here is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BackendDashboardModule } from '@dashboard/back-end-dashboard';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: 'my_db.db',
      entities: ['/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    BackendDashboardModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In `my_db.db` SQLite database, I have created a `View` which contains exactly the same columns as `summary.entity.ts`.

When I run `ng serve api`, I get the following error:

> [Nest] 11160   - 17/08/2021, 13:00:40   [NestFactory] Starting Nest
> application... [Nest] 11160   - 17/08/2021, 13:00:40
> [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +565ms [Nest]
> 11160   - 17/08/2021, 13:00:40   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule
> dependencies initialized +7ms No type errors found Version: typescript
> 4.0.7 Time: 17935ms [Nest] 11160   - 17/08/2021, 13:01:17   **[TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database.** Retrying (1)...
> +36756ms Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/Documents and Settings'
> at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1043:3)
> at GlobSync._readdir (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:286:41)
> at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:265:20)
> at GlobSync._readdir (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:274:17)
> at GlobSync._processReaddir (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:135:22)
> at GlobSync._process (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
> at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:378:10)
> at GlobSync._process (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:128:10)
> at new GlobSync (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:46:10)
> at Function.globSync [as sync] (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules\glob\sync.js:24:10)

When I change my `app.module.ts` like the following:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BackendDashboardModule } from '@dashboard/back-end-dashboard';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: 'my_db.db',
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    BackendDashboardModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then I get the following error:

> [Nest] 5276   - 17/08/2021, 13:04:42   [NestFactory] Starting Nest
> application... [Nest] 5276   - 17/08/2021, 13:04:43   [InstanceLoader]
> AppModule dependencies initialized +352ms [Nest] 5276   - 17/08/2021,
> 13:04:43   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized
> +2ms [Nest] 5276   - 17/08/2021, 13:04:43   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +55ms [Nest] 5276   -
> 17/08/2021, 13:04:43   [ExceptionHandler] **No repository for "Summary"
> was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current
> "default" connection?** +167ms RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository
> for "Summary" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in
> current "default" connection?
> at RepositoryNotFoundError.TypeORMError [as constructor] (C:\projects\my-project\src\error\TypeORMError.ts:7:9)
> at new RepositoryNotFoundError (C:\projects\my-project\src\error\RepositoryNotFoundError.ts:10:9)
> at EntityManager.getRepository (C:\projects\my-project\src\entity-manager\EntityManager.ts:931:19)
> at Connection.getRepository (C:\projects\my-project\src\connection\Connection.ts:339:29)
> at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm.providers.js:16:30)
> at Injector.instantiateClass (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:289:55)
> at callback (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:42:41)
> at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:114:24)
> at Injector.loadInstance (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:46:9)
> at Injector.loadProvider (C:\projects\my-project\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:68:9)

Comment: try to add entiti manually. enttites:[Summary]

Comment: @Yilmaz, Do you mean that there are no ways to add the entities automatically (in the case of lots of entities)?

Comment: did   that workk?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue. You have to set  `autoLoadEntities: true` in appModule.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'sqlite',
      database: 'my_db.db',
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      // add this setting
      autoLoadEntities: true,

      synchronize: false,
    }),
    BackendDashboardModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
```